# How to take running cmd window logs inside a .bat script

Tags: batch-file, command, omake

```
echo off
echo .
echo .
echo .
start /wait cmd.exe /c omake mv=%~2 ecu_build > ecu_log.txt
```

Please help me how to log the cmd window output the above code is not working It always creates an empty file {ecu_log.txt}

Comment: The above lines are written inside a .bat script which is called from a make file

Comment: you are missing some double quotes, else the redirect is passed to catch the output of the first `cmd` instance which is nothing `start /wait cmd.exe /c "omake mv=%~2 ecu_build>ecu_log.txt"` but anyway, how about just `omake mv=%~2 ecu_build>ecu_log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It is working and logging the cmd output but i observe below errors:::                                                                                                                                           Error: Multiple versions of "\frdcc_motorcontrol\project\asm_bk\output\EVD2\quicktest\quicktest_ecu_log.txt" were accessed during build script.
Interference from another process?

Comment: start /wait cmd.exe /c "omake mv=%~2 ecu_build>ecu_log.txt"

Comment: The first option chosen but even if i tried the second options but the errors were coming

Comment: ok, so that error is coming from your build, not the way you are running the redirect.